# Is there a Haskell code formatter?

Tags: haskell, code-formatting

I used to write

```
data A = A {
      a :: Double
    }
    deriving(Eq, Show)
```

but now i prefer

```
data A = A {
      a :: Double
    } deriving(Eq, Show)
```

I think the answer will be no, but i ask anyway: is there a code formatter for Haskell?

Comment: A few years late but hindent exists now, I've updated my accept answer with it.

Comment: check out brittany

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## New answer

I have now written [hindent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hindent), which is written in terms of [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts). It has Emacs and Vim support.

---

## Old answer

There is [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) which will parse your code and it has a pretty printing module for printing the AST to a string. E.g.

```
import Language.Haskell.Exts

main = interact codeFormat

codeFormat = check . fmap reformat . parseModuleWithComments where
  reformat = prettyPrint
  check r = case r of
              ParseOk a -> a
              ParseFailed loc err -> error $ show (loc,err)
```

Example:

```
λ> putStrLn $ codeFormat "module X where x = 1 where { y 1 = 2; y _ = 2 }"
module X where
x = 1
  where y 1 = 2
        y _ = 2
```

Alternatively you can write a pretty printer yourself (even based on the above if you just want to specialise), and then you can have whatever style you want. Replace `prettyPrint` with your own. The AST is very straight-forward.

Then you can hook it up with Emacs to reformat every time you hit save or something.

Comment: put this in your ~./ghci:  :set prompt "λ>"

Comment: Your code does not type-check with haskell-src-exts-1.13.5. Also, is there a way to pretty-print it including the comments?

Comment: the code can be type-checked if you change to other parse function, but seems there're no support to preserve comments in the source, only collecting comments into a list, don't know why it's useful to do that.

Answer (score 12):

There's [stylish-haskell](https://github.com/jaspervdj/stylish-haskell/blob/master/README.markdown) which can do precisely what you want.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a small script for that same purpose: https://github.com/djv/small/blob/master/tidy.hs
I call it from vim to reformat my code.

Answer (score 2):

To print an AST with comments you would need [ExactPrint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Annotated-ExactPrint.html)

```
exactPrint :: ExactP ast => ast SrcSpanInfo -> [Comment] -> String
```

but `exactPrint` won't pretty print your sources.

I've written [a small tool](https://github.com/Zane-XY/haskell-pretty) you can call it with Vim as an external formatter.

```
prettyHS :: String -> String
prettyHS src
  = case parseFileContentsWithComments defaultParseMode src of
        ParseOk (ast, _) -> prettyPrint ast
        _ -> src
```